# Sharing a sticker to Instagram Story broken?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, instagram

EDIT: Facebook issue : https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2434932356771915/

---

I'm trying to share a bitmap to an Instagram story sticker.
But it loads Instagram, but doesn't show any sticker, no background colors, only a black story screen. 
What is wrong with this code ? I check if file was in the external data cache directory and that's good.

According to [Facebook's Instagram documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/) :

- I added read/write rights to storage and a provider to my AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <provider
      android:authorities="my.app.id.fileprovider"
      android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
      android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
  </provider>
  ```
- I added a file_paths.xml to share my external cache folder to other apps

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
      <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <external-cache-path name="share" path="."/>
      </paths>
  </resources>
  ```
- I create a bitmap from a drawable, write it to a file on the external cache dir, and apply the Intent like example in the docs

  ```
  public static void sendStickerToInstagram() {
      Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.sticker);
      File extStorageDirectory = context.getExternalCacheDir();
      File stickerFile = new File(extStorageDirectory, "sticker.png");

      try {
          FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(stickerFile);
          bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
          outStream.flush();
          outStream.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e("TEST", e.getMessage());
      }

      Uri stickerUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "my.app.id.fileprovider", stickerFile);
      // Uri stickerUri = Uri.fromFile(stickerFile);
      String linkUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com";

      Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
      intent.setType("image/*");
      intent.putExtra("interactive_asset_uri", stickerUri);
      intent.putExtra("content_url", linkUrl);
      intent.putExtra("top_background_color", "#33FF33");
      intent.putExtra("bottom_background_color", "#FF00FF");

      grantUriPermission("com.instagram.android", stickerUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
      if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
      }
  }
  ```

Most strange part is when I test to share my sticker as background, it works, so the file is loaded as espected, with all permissions.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
    intent.setDataAndType(stickerUri, "image/*");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.putExtra("content_url", linkUrl);

    if (activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

Any idea why I can't share a sticker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry... It's not you. It's Instagram. :P

Their most recent release of Instagram on Android broke the 
 `com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY` intent. 
 Keep an eye on this thread for updates.

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2434932356771915/

Comment: Oh thank you! I was worried my mistake was too big for me to see it!